# Как сделать функцию умножения матриц, чтобы передавать ей массивы различных размеров

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Например, просто в процессе выполнения программы писать `multMatrix(mat1,mat2,mat3)`, а потом матрицы других размеров, допустим, `multMatrix(mat4,mat5,mat6)`, а то получилось как-то так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

const int commonROWSandCOLUMNS = 3;
const int numofROWS = 3;
const int numofCOLUMNS = 3;

void multMatrix(
    int matrix1[numofROWS][commonROWSandCOLUMNS], 
    int matrix2[commonROWSandCOLUMNS][numofCOLUMNS], 
    int matrix3[numofROWS][numofCOLUMNS]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numofROWS; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < numofCOLUMNS; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < commonROWSandCOLUMNS; i3++) {
                matrix3[i][i2] += matrix1[i][i3] * matrix2[i3][i2];
            }
        }
    }
}

int matrix1[3][3] = {
    {9,3,4},
    {2,8,2},
    {1,5,6}
};

int matrix2[3][3] = {
    {9,0,0},
    {1,0,0},
    {8,0,0}
};

int matrix3[3][3];

int main()
{
    multMatrix(matrix1,matrix2,matrix3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 3; i2++) {
            cout << matrix3[i][i2] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Или подскажите какую-нибудь библиотеку, или надо использовать динамические массивы?

Comment: О чем именно вопрос? Если вам обязательно требуется представлять матрицы именно голыми 2D массивами - то это один вопрос. Если способ представления матриц не принципиален - то это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: Можно перегрузить функцию. Можно создать свой тип данных, который будет представлять матрицу вне зависимости от ее размера (почитайте про классы или структуры, если не знаете как это сделать).

Comment: Подскажу библиотеку: boost::qvm. В этой библиотеке есть уже реализованные матрицы, а также вы можете определить и свои типы. К тому же она интегрирована с библиотекой boost::geometry (это если помимо матриц вам нужны еще и геометрические фигуры).

Comment: Что значит способ представления матриц? Нужно сделать функцию, в которую можно будет подставлять матрицы различных размеров, а то сейчас размер массивов определен заранее.

Comment: В стандарте языка матрицы всегда фиксированного размера. Вам нужно будет создать свою собственную структуру.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

class mat {
public:
    float **m;
    int arr;
    int col;
    mat(int arr1, int col1) {
        m = new float*[arr1];
        for (int x = 0; x < arr1; x++) {
            m[x] = new float[col1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col1; i2++) {
                m[i][i2] = 0;
            }
        }

        arr = arr1;
        col = col1;

    }
    mat() {};
    void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col; i2++) {
                cout << m[i][i2] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    void fill_rand(float from, float to) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col; i2++) {
                m[i][i2] = from + static_cast<float>(rand()) / static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX / (to - from));
            }
        }
    }
    void resize(int arr1, int col1) {
        for (int x = 0; x < arr; x++) {
            delete[] m[x];
        }
        delete[] m;

        m = new float*[arr1];
        for (int x = 0; x < arr1; x++) {
            m[x] = new float[col1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1; i++) {
            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < col1; i2++) {
                m[i][i2] = 0;
            }
        }

        arr = arr1;
        col = col1;

    }
    float determinant() {
        float d = 0;

        if (col == 1)
        {
            d = m[0][0];
            return d;
        }
        if (col == 2)
        {
            d = m[0][0] * m[1][1] - m[0][1] * m[1][0];
            return d;
        }
        else 
        {
            mat matrix((arr - 1), (col - 1));

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < col; i1++)
            {
                //Creating small matrix
                int count = 0;
                for (int i2 = 1; i2 < arr; i2++)
                {
                    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < col; i3++)
                    {
                        if (i3 != i1)
                        {
                            matrix.m[(i2 - 1)][count] = m[i2][i3];
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    count = 0;
                }

                if (i1 % 2 == 0) 
                {
                    d += m[0][i1] * matrix.determinant();
                }
                else 
                {
                    d -= m[0][i1] * matrix.determinant();
                }
            }
            return d;
        }
    }
};
mat operator * (mat matrix1, mat matrix2) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix2.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix2.col; i2++) {
            for (int i3 = 0; i3 < matrix1.col; i3++) {
                result.m[i][i2] += matrix1.m[i][i3] * matrix2.m[i3][i2];
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator * (mat matrix1, float num) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = matrix1.m[i][i1] * num;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator * (float num, mat matrix1) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = num * matrix1.m[i][i1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator + (mat matrix1, mat matrix2) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix2.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix2.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = matrix1.m[i][i1] + matrix2.m[i][i1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator + (mat matrix1, float num) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = matrix1.m[i][i1] + num;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator + (float num, mat matrix1) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = num + matrix1.m[i][i1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator - (mat matrix1, mat matrix2) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix2.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix2.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = matrix1.m[i][i1] - matrix2.m[i][i1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator - (mat matrix1, float num) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = matrix1.m[i][i1] - num;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat operator - (float num, mat matrix1) {
    mat result(matrix1.arr, matrix1.col);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix1.arr; i++) {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix1.col; i1++) {
            result.m[i][i1] = num - matrix1.m[i][i1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
mat transpose(mat matrix) {
    mat m(matrix.col, matrix.arr);
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.col; i++) {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix.arr; i2++) {
            m.m[i][i2] = matrix.m[i2][i];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
mat inverse(mat matrix) {
    mat m(matrix.arr, matrix.col);
    
    //Case when arr_num = 1
    if (matrix.arr == 1) 
    {
        m.m[0][0] = 1/matrix.m[0][0];
        return m;
    }

    //Creating minor matrix
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    mat m2((matrix.arr - 1), (matrix.col - 1));
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < matrix.arr; i1++) 
    {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix.col; i2++)
        {
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < matrix.arr; j1++)
            {
                for (int j2 = 0; j2 < matrix.col; j2++)
                {
                    if (j1 != i1 && j2 != i2) 
                    {
                        m2.m[count1][count2] = matrix.m[j1][j2];
                        count2++;
                        if (count2 == (matrix.col - 1)) 
                        {
                            count2 = 0;
                            count1++;
                            if (count1 == (matrix.arr - 1))
                            {
                                count1 = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            m.m[i1][i2] = m2.determinant();
        }
    }

    //Changing signs on some numbers
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < m.arr; i1++)
    {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < m.col; i2++)
        {
            if ((i1 + i2) % 2 != 0) 
            {
                m.m[i1][i2] = -m.m[i1][i2];
            }
        }
    }

    m = (1/matrix.determinant()) * transpose(m);

    return m;
}

int main()
{
    mat j(7,7);
    j.fill_rand(0,7);
    j.print();
    cout << "\n";
    inverse(j).print();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: После конструктора `mat() {}` и `resize` будет крах памяти. `mat m;m.resize(1,1); BUMM` Нужно исправить конструктор на `mat():m(),arr(),col() {}`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, извините, не очень понял, что вы сказали.

Comment: Ваш конструктор пустой матрицы **не** устанавливает никакие значения переменных `m`,`arr`,`col`. Там будут находиться случайные значения (*мусор*) памяти. И при вызове `resize` или деструктора матрицы будет вызвано исключение неправильного удаления указателя. Я предлагал, чтобы конструктор задавал нулевые значения этим переменным.

Comment: А так как вы даже не написали деструктор, то будет утечка памяти всегда.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, понял, спасибо.